# Static IP Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 with 2 Ethernet ports

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp, static-ip

Bit of info:
We're running Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 with 2 Ethernet Ports. On port enp2s0 we run hardware trough a static IP. On port enp3s0 we have a 'normal' DHCP internet connection. When enp3s0 is connected we have connection with Internet and we can browse the internet and run our application. The moment we connect port enp2s0 the internet connection of enp3s0 is not working anymore.

I've set the static ip of enp2s0 trough the settings UI.

Anyone got an idea what I do wrong?

Thanks for the effort.

Regards, Arjen

Comment: What static IP settings? What hardware is connected to enp2s0? What DHCP address on enp3s0? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @heynnema When going into settings you can set the wired connection to Manual. In there I set it to: "192.168.0.1 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.0.1". The hardware connected is a board to connect to electronic locks. DHCP adress is automatically set by the network. Sadly I don't have access to the machine currently, so can't fill in the command.

Comment: Isn't 192.168.0.1 also the gateway/router for the enp3s0 interface? Can't have two similar addresses.